# Unable to populate dropdown list for null query result in jsp

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu, null

After taking lot of efforts finally I am here to ask the question. I am working on JSP dropdown list where I am populating the list items from database. At one point I am not able to get the solution that when the value is `null`

```
<%
  String v_divcode = v_div_code;    //Any division code between A to D                  
  String sql = " SELECT DIV_CODE, DIV_NAME "+
               " FROM tbl_division "+
               " where show_FLAG='Y' "; 

            stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){%>
                <option value="<%=rs.getString("div_code")%>" <%=v_divcode.equals(rs.getString("div_code"))?"Selected":""%>><%=rs.getString("div_name")%></option>
            <%
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
           %>
```

As per above code I am able to populate the list when `v_divcode = (division code between A to D)` but if `v_divcode=null` then I am not able to get the list items in dropdown. I have tried everything. Please help me to solve this issue. Thank You.

Comment: Do you get any errors? If not, I would try to add some logging, at least e.g. `System.out.println(rs.getString("div_code"));` in the `while` loop, to monitor what's happening (i.e. if there are really some records).

Comment: Yeah, it prints the records if it finds the `v_divcode` is having some value and if `v_divcode` is `null` then it throws `NullPointerException`. @Jozef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When v_divcode will be null, your code will throw NullPointerException near <%=v_divcode.equals....

You should perform null check for that.

Comment: I have also tried that thing its also not working at all @Jekin

Comment: As you suggested me I have taken the care of null check but still the problem persisting.

Comment: `if(!(v_divcode.isEmpty())){
             while(rs.next()){
               
              v_divcode=rs.getString("div_code");
              out.println(v_divcode+" ");
               }'                                   @Jekin
               }

Comment: bro I have told you to perform null check first like this if(v_divcode!=null){ your logic}

Answer (score 0):

If `v_divcode` contains  `null` then your code will throw `NullPointerException`. To avoid such issue you may try like this:

```
if(v_divcode==null){

   //Your error handeling code goes here

}
```